# Storing a drawn map path using core data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dictionary, overlay

I'm creating an app that is based off the breadcrumb sample code provide by Apple and I would like to store the overlay path drawn by the app in core data. I would then like to recall this data later and draw it on a map again. Is this possible? What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. Make a managed object with latitude, longitude and timestamp properties, then store them (together as one object) as they come in. To display them on a map, reverse the process and create pins from the objects. You should do the fetch ordered by timestamp to create a path.